# Codeigniter 2.2, MySQL - Get all ids after csv import

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am importing data from the **csv** and I need to get ids of the rows added and insert that id into new table **pesonInfo**. The query have **IGNORE** in order not to duplicate entries. Is there some way for me to do this task?

The code:

```
$files  = directory_map('./assets/csv/');
foreach ($files as $file) :
    $csv = './assets/csv/' . $file;
    $q = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$csv'
                    IGNORE INTO TABLE person FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
                    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                    IGNORE 1 ROWS
                    (personal_name, personal_lastname,personal_country, personal_address,contact_email,dateadded);";
    $this->db->query($q);
    unlink($csv);
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, You need to run 2 more queries for this.

The first query should be run before your "LOAD DATA" query which have something like

```
$q = $this->db->query("SELECT MAX(id) max_id FROM person")->row();
$max_id = $q->max_id;
```

The second query which you'll run after loading the data in file to get the ids

```
$q = $this->db->where('id >', $max_id)->get('person');
$result = $q->result();
```

Now you can foreach $result get the id of the row, which you can store in an array for later use or do whatever you want.